# Where is TreeView class

Tags: xaml, view, tree, uwp, controls

Which nuget package contains the TreeView class for UWP promised in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.treeview ?

I thought it was coming in W10 Fall Creators Update but I have that and I can't find TreeView, TreeViewNode, etc.

I am referencing Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.0.1 and NETStandard.Library v2.0.1 in my UWP project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 01/05/2018**

[TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.treeview) control is available in April 2018 Update

---

**Old Post**

[TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.treeview) control is not available in Fall Creators Update

> The TreeView control has been removed, but will be back soon in the next release of Windows and the Preview SDK.

Source: [Windows 10 SDK Preview Build 16257 and Mobile Emulator Build 15235 Released](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/08/08/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-16257-mobile-emulator-build-15235-released)

**Update:**

[TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.treeview) control is now available in [Windows 10 SDK Preview Build 17061 or above](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK)

Check the API Updates and Additions section in [Windows 10 SDK Preview Build 17061 now available blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/12/19/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-17061-now-available)

> public class TreeView : Control
>     public sealed class TreeViewCollapsedEventArgs
>     public sealed class TreeViewExpandingEventArgs
>     public class TreeViewItem : ListViewItem
>     public sealed class TreeViewItemInvokedEventArgs
>     public class TreeViewItemTemplateSettings : DependencyObject
>     public class TreeViewList : ListView
>     public class TreeViewNode : DependencyObject
>     public enum TreeViewSelectionMode
>     public class TreeViewItemAutomationPeer : ListViewItemAutomationPeer, IExpandCollapseProvider
>     public class TreeViewListAutomationPeer : SelectorAutomationPeer

Comment: Thanks, Vijay. Any idea where I can get the pre-release version?

Comment: @sjb I don't know. Follow [blogs.windows.com](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps). Also, If you got your answer then consider Mark as Answer

Comment: @sjb-sjb TreeView control is now available. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I marked this as answer but then unmarked it because this is an Insider release only. I am anxiously awaiting the regular release. But it sounds like it is getting there !!

Comment: @sjb-sjb It will be released with next major update in April 2018.

Comment: @sjb-sjb TreeView control is available in April 2018 Update

Comment: Hooray!!!  To get it, just install Windows 10 version 1803 (build 17134), download the corresponding Windows 10 SDK, and set your target platform minimum version to 17134 in your Visual Studio project.

Comment: The 1803 release is missing ItemsSource. I hope this will come in the next release.